# API or getting data from google calendars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, calendar

I'm setting up a calendar for my clients website. Currently I have an iframe displaying my google calendar to give them a jist of an easy peezy calendar embed. This way they can go to their google.com/calendar page and update any events from there.

However, on mobile it displays the Iframe in full, and doesn't sit real well.

Is there a way to get the data being transferred to this iframe and just pass in a Notification list; that is more mobile friendly.

I suppose something like this:

[image]

Comment: _"Is there a way to get the data being transferred to this iframe"_ i think so no, but you could use the [google calendar api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/)

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I needed. Now I just have to figure out how to use it :) Thanks!